# Frying a Turkey in a Brew Kettle

Tags: kettle, boil-kettle, brewpot

Family wants me to fry a turkey in my 14 gallon brew kettle.  I'm all for fried turkey but worried about lasting effects on my kettle.  Anyone have experience with something like this? Also open to suggestions on frying a turkey.

Comment: So, how did it go? Is it possible to get it clean?

Comment: Terrible! I've deleted my previous comment saying it worked great.  It's been a nearly 3 years and I'm still getting some oil sheens.  Head retention hasn't been terrible, but not great either.  I seriously regret doing this.  Also, my kettle has a large diameter so I ended up using way too much oil.  

Failure all around!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a can of metal. If you don't feel you can get the surface clean after the fry (perhaps because of carbonization of organic matter stuck to the surface), then that will be a problem. If you can, then it's a clean surface you will have no problems brewing with in the future.

I'd say: roast away!  If there's a problem, lobby to get your family to replace and in fact improve your brew kettle as a remuneration for your trouble. ;)

(Edit:) But most likely, you're going to easily remove any residual oils with soap, because that's what soap does, and any organic matter stuck to the surface will also be easily removed with a bit of elbow grease and a semi-abrasive surface.

Happy Thanksgiving!